# If lower consistency level is good then why we need to have a higher consistency(QUORUM,ALL) level in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

While going through Datastax tutorial I learned that
1)Lower consistency level is quicker for read and write whereas, it's much longer if we use higher consistency level
2) Lower consistency level also ensures high availability of data.

My question is 
if Lower CL is good then we can always set CL as ONE, 
why do we need QUORUM and ALL consistency levels?

Comment: Lower consistency doesn't ensure high availability of data, it ensures high availability of cluster. If for example you have replication factor 3, then with consistency level of one you can lose 2 replicas and still stay in the game. Quorum is what you should use if you require high consistency from client perspective, while tolerating availability issues. If you always read and write in quorum, you overcome the eventual consistency (== no guarantee for consistency) of cassandra.

Comment: If a hammer is good, why would I ever need a saw? It's all about using the right tool for the job. Or, "horses for courses" as our British friends so poetically phrase it.

Answer (score 3):

It ultimately depends on the application using Cassandra.  If the application is ok with serving up data that may be under-replicated or slightly stale, then `LOCAL_ONE` should be fine.  If the application absolutely cannot provide a wrong answer, or if written rows are not being successfully read consistently, then perhaps `LOCAL_QUORUM` may be more applicable.

I tell my application teams the same thing.  Start with `LOCAL_ONE`, and and work with it through testing.  If you don't have any problems, then continue using it.  If you do experience stale data, and your application is more read-sensitive, then try *writing* at `LOCAL_QUORUM` and continue reading at `LOCAL_ONE`.  And if that doesn't help, then perhaps the application may need both at `QUORUM.`

Again, that's why application teams need to do thorough testing.

And just to address it, `ALL` is a useful consistency level because it invokes a read repair.  Essentially, if you have a table which you know is missing data, and you don't want to run a costly `nodetool repair` on it, you can set your consistency to `ALL` and read from it.  I find this trick to be most-useful when addressing issues with multi-DC clusters having issues with `system_auth`.

But you probably wouldn't want to use `ALL` from within an application.  Or if you did, it'd be for a very specific edge case.

Answer (score 1):

The real meat of database like Cassandra is "**eventual consistency**": it won't enforce strong consistency when you first write data to the database. rather, it gives you option to choose a weaker consistency level like "one" to reach high writing performance, and then later when you query data, as long as this rule "**Read_Consistency_level + Write_consistency_level >= the RF policy (Replication factor)**" satisfies, you won't have stale data.

It's risky if you can't fulfill the above rule since you might get either stale or contradictory (sometimes new, sometimes old) data.