# Proper Consistency Level to read 'everything'

Tags: cassandra

I'm creating a sync program to periodically copy our Cassandra data into another database. The database I'm copying from only gets INSERTs - data is never UPDATEd or DELETEd. I would like to address Cassandra's eventual consistency model in two ways:

1 - Each sync scan overlaps the last by a certain time span. For example, if the scan happens every hour, then each scan looks an hour and a half backwards. The data contains a unique key, so reading the same record in more than one scan is not an issue.

2 - I use a Consistency level of ALL to ensure that I'm scanning all of the nodes on the cluster for the data.

Is ALL the best Consistency for this situation? I just need to see a record on any node, I don't care if it appears on any other nodes. But I don't want to miss any INSERTed records either. But I also don't want to experience timeouts or performance issues because Cassandra is waiting for multiple nodes to see that record.

To complicate this a bit more, this Cassandra network is made up of 6 clusters in different geographic locations. I am only querying one. My assumption is that the overlap mentioned in #1 will eventually catch up records that exist on other clusters.

The query I'm doing is like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM transactions WHERE userid=:userid AND transactiondate>:(lastscan-overlap)
```

Where **userid** is the partioning key and **transactiondate** is a clustering column. The list of userId's is sourced elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I use a Consistency level of All to ensure that I'm scanning all of the nodes on the cluster for the data

So consistency `ALL` has more to do with the number of data replicas read than it does with the number of nodes contacted.  If you have a replication factor (RF) of 3 and query a single row at `ALL`, then Cassandra will hash your partition key to figure out the three nodes responsible for that row, contact all 3 nodes, and wait for all 3 to respond.

> I just need to see a record on one node

So I think you'd be fine with `LOCAL_ONE`, in this regard.

The only possible advantage of using `ALL`, is that it actually does help to enforce data consistency by triggering a read repair 100% of the time.  So if eventual consistency is a concern, that's a "plus."  But `*_ONE` is definitely faster.

> The CL documentation talks a lot about 'stale data', but I am interested in 'new data'

In your case, I don't see stale data as a possibility, so you should be ok there.  The issue that you would face instead, is in the event that one or more replicas failed during the write operation, querying at `LOCAL_ONE` may or may not get you the only replica that actually exists.  So your data wouldn't be stale vs. new, it'd be exists vs. does not exist.  One point I talk about in the linked answer, is that perhaps *writing* at a higher consistency level and *reading* at `LOCAL_ONE` might work for your use case.

A few years ago, I wrote an answer about the different consistency levels, which you might find helpful in this case:
[If lower consistency level is good then why we need to have a higher consistency(QUORUM,ALL) level in Cassandra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49264605/if-lower-consistency-level-is-good-then-why-we-need-to-have-a-higher-consistency/49264916#49264916)

Comment: I've added a bit more, but you're correct; my question is about the CL. The CL documentation talks a lot about 'stale data', but I am interested in 'new data' (gotten by using a rather open-ended query),

Comment: @MarcBernier Edit made.